# How to create a Google Authentication for iOS in UE?

Tags: c++, mobile, google-authentication, unreal-engine4, google-account

I am developing a mobile app for my school with Unreal Engine. I am using C++ (looking for free viable compilers). For said app, I need to create user accounts, and my CS teacher wants me to use Google to authenticate accounts.

Due to the very limited amount of data on said integration is available online, I was unable to find any resources. How do I add a "connect Google account" function to my app?

Thank you.

This is for an iOS mobile application that allows the FBLA presidents to manage chapters: (https://www.fbla-pbl.org/competitive-event/mobile-application-development-fbla/)

Comment: Try this: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin

Comment: "_I am developing..._" - Yet you chose to share nothing of what you've developed so far.